# Why does dojo's xhr call to get JSP file content not process the onShow event in InternetExplorer as it does for Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: ajax, jsp, dojo

I'm trying to resolve a problem seen only with the IE browser but not Firefox or Chrome.  I'm using the dojox.widget.Wizard along with the dojox.widget.WizardPane where each pane in the wizard gets added to the Wizard like so:

```
nextWizPane = new dojox.widget.WizardPane({
paneId: chosenPaneId,
passFunction: handleNext,
onShow: showingPane
}).placeAt(wizard, newPaneIndex);

loadPaneContents(nextWizPane);
```

where the loadPaneContents() function dynamically loads the contents for the new WizardPane by using the "dojo/request/xhr" module.  The xhr's "then" function accepts the anonymous callback function which accepts the contents of a JSP file which is finally used to set the contents of the WizardPane like so:

```
xhr(contextPath+"/lib/wizardPanes/UrsPage_"+wizPane.paneId+".jsp", 
  {sync:true}).then(function(responseFromXhr) {
    nextWizPane.set("content", responseFromXhr);
});
```

where the file that xhr is loading, e.g. UrsPage_1_1_1.jsp, defines the contents for the wizard pane.  The contents of the UrsPage_1_1_1.jsp file starts out like:

```
<%@page session="true" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:setBundle basename="/WEB-INF/config/resourcebundle"/>

<div wizardpageidline data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="1_1_1" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="" paneName="Contact Information">
  <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="show" data-dojo-args="e">
    console.log("UP111 onShow form2");      
    alert("UP111 onShow form2");
    require(
      { packages:[ { name:'lib', location:'/lib' } ] },
    ["lib/UrsController",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(ursController, dojoOn, dom){

        dojoOn(dom.byId("mailingAddressSameAsPrincipal"), "change", function(){
            console.log("UP111 changed SameAsMailingAddress this.checked="+this.checked);
            alert("UP111 checked Same As box="+this.checked);
        });
    });
  </script>

...<snipped dojo/dijit/HTML markup>
</div>
```

The log and alert calls above appear when this runs in Chrome and Firefox, but are completely ignored and unexecuted when run in IE8.  What am I missing?  The JSP file's markup that is snipped does contain dojo/dijit markup that is successfully parsed in both IE, Firefox and Chrome, so it's not like the whole file is being ignored by the dojo parser, just the onShow  for the outer .   Any help would be appreciated on how to debug this issue.

Thank you,
Gregor

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this same issue in IE11 and have narrowed it down to this: in an asynch block, it appears that IE has lost scope of the config.contextPath. You may have to get creative on how to gain this value and store it in your widget as a property that can be passed to your asynch call. Example: 
   var prefix = config.contextPath;
   topic.publish("/widget/selected", row.id, prefix);  //may need this.prefix depending upon where you gain/store the property and where used.

For my purpose, the code executed fine when IE debug panel or console was open, but failed when console was closed. Alert statements were the only thing that could aid in this matter. Basically, confirm the url you are building before executing the ajax